# Repurposing smoke detector power as fixture power

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, code-compliance, smoke-detectors

I removed a wired smoke detector and replaced it with a popular wifi-enabled battery-powered model. I'm left with a box that has:

- a black wire
- a white wire
- a red wire
- a ground

[image]

I'm assuming the black and white to be regular 120v, neutral and hot (I'll confirm with a voltmeter). I'm assuming the red is some form of traveller that allows one detector to have the other trigger at the same time (I won't mess with it because I don't know the voltage it wants, but I'm tempted to connect red and black, see if the other detector starts ringing).

If I confirm the above, the question becomes:

Can I simply remove the adapter for the smoke detector, cap the red wire and re-purpose the black/white to power a fixture with a smart bulb? I'll leave the current neutral/hot connectivity continue. I realize I won't get a wall switch, but I don't care. I'd be perfectly happy with a smart bulb, maybe a motion-detector light.

Would it be a code violation to do so ? (location is Quebec, Canada)

Should I expect this to be a dedicated circuit for only the smoke detectors ?

Comment: You'll probably fry the other detectors if you connect red to black, BTW; while the red wire *is* being used as a smoke-alarm interconnect signalling wire in this case, it runs at smoke-detector-battery-voltage, not 120VAC.

Comment: yeah, just saw your other post where you suggest 9V :-). Definitely will not mess with it.

Comment: The possible code violation is my concern here--the risk being that you inadvertently disable your life-preserving protections with non-standard usage. There's no problem using the wires for a light otherwise--they're functionally identical to any other black/white pair in your light and outlet circuits.

Comment: I don't think Code lets you do that.  Check with your AHJ.